# How to add message to a field in a form

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet code and I would like to a message to the field which the FIELD Variable is holding. Here I'm adding a red colored border to the field:
(field.style.borderColor = 'red';)

and now I would like to add a message to it right after setting the red border.
How do I do that ?

```
    // Show erroroneous fields in red
    var formFields = thisForm.find('input,textarea,select');
    var numberOfElements = formFields.length;

    for (var fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < numberOfElements; fieldIndex++) {

      var field = formFields[fieldIndex];
      field.style.borderColor = '';

      for (var key in jqXHR.responseJSON) {
        //if (jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty(key) && field.id.includes(key)) {
        if (field.id.endsWith(key) || field.id.endsWith(key + '_id')) {
          //console.log(key + " = " + jqXHR.responseJSON[key]);
          field.style.borderColor = 'red';
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any response.

DANI

Comment: Depending on your HTML structure, you could [create a new element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for the message and [insert it adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) to the field element. Can we see your HTML and a sample of the JSON?

Comment: Will this snippet help ?
<form class="new_address" id="new_address" enctype="multipart/form-data"         <div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col field">
    <label for="address_line_1_Address line 1">Address line 1</label> <span style="color: red;">*</span>
    <input placeholder="Address line 1" class="form-control" title="Address line 1" type="text" name="address[address_line_1]" id="address_address_line_1">
  </div>
</div>

Comment: The jason response:

jqXHR.responseJSON
{country: Array(2), address_line_1: Array(1)}
country: (2) ["must exist", "can't be blank"]
address_line_1: ["can't be blank"]
__proto__: Object

I will be using only - address_line_1: ["can't be blank"].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have managed to resolve it:

```
    // Show erroroneous fields in red
    var formFields = thisForm.find('input,textarea,select');
    var numberOfElements = formFields.length;

    for (var fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < numberOfElements; fieldIndex++) {

      var field = formFields[fieldIndex];
      field.style.borderColor = '';

      for (var key in jqXHR.responseJSON) {
        //if (jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty(key) && field.id.includes(key)) {
        if (field.id.endsWith(key) || field.id.endsWith(key + '_id')) {
          //console.log(key + " = " + jqXHR.responseJSON[key]);
          field.style.borderColor = 'red';
          var currentElement = formFields[fieldIndex];
          $( "<p class = 'errMsg'>"+jqXHR.responseJSON[key].valueOf()+"</p>" ).insertAfter( currentElement );
        }
      }
    }
```